# How I can convert vector of hex digits into a u64?

Tags: rust

I have byte string like this `["80", "1c", "07", "53", "1b", "fc", "c7", "01"]` and I would like to convert it to long little endian, result should be something like this `128348308690640000`

How would I best go about doing that?

Comment: What exactly are you starting with, could you be precise? You say "byte string" but that looks like an array of 2-character strings containing hex digits.

Comment: ah sorry , i'll edited the tittle, that's a vector actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to combine `from_str_radix` and `from_le_bytes`. Quick example (with anyhow for error handling, you'll need to think about what you want to do if your input slice doesn't have 8 strings, or if one of them is not a hex digit.):

```
use anyhow::Context;

fn hex_bytes_to_u64(input: &[&str]) -> anyhow::Result<u64> {
    anyhow::ensure!(input.len() == 8, "expected 8 hex bytes");
    let bytes = input
        .iter()
        .map(|s| u8::from_str_radix(s, 16))
        .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()
        .context("Hex byte parse failure")?;
    Ok(u64::from_le_bytes(bytes.try_into().expect("u64 doesn't have 8 bytes?")))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a15390bb7f36b23b74d5c206b576afd9)